# MERGE Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, upsert

I have a SQL Server 2008 many-to-many relationship table (`Assets`) with two columns:

```
AssetId (PK, FK, uniqueidentifier, not null)
AssetCategoryId (PK, FK, int, not null)
```

In my project, I need to take rows from this table, and insert them into a replicated database periodically. So, I have two databases that are exactly the same (constraints included).

In order to "copy" from one database to the other, I use a MERGE statement with a temp table. I insert up to 50 records into the temp table, then merge the temp table with the `Assets` table I am copying into as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #Assets (AssetId UniqueIdentifier, AssetCategoryId Int);
INSERT INTO #Assets (AssetId, AssetCategoryId) VALUES ('ed05bac3-7a92-46aa-8822-2d882b137597', 44), ('dc5e3082-e2eb-4bdf-a640-94e0f59411ed', 22) ... ;

MERGE INTO Assets WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS Target 
USING #Assets AS Source 
ON Target.AssetId = Source.AssetId AND Target.AssetCategoryId = Source.AssetCategoryId 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN 
INSERT (AssetId,AssetCategoryId) VALUES (Source.AssetId,Source.AssetCategoryId);
```

This works great, for the most part. However, once in a while, I get the error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Assets'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Assets'. The duplicate key value is
>   (dc5e3082-e2eb-4bdf-a640-94e0f59411ed, 22).  The statement has been
>   terminated.

When I check in the `Assets` table, no such record exists... so I am confused how I would be inserting a duplicate key.

Any idea what is going on here?

**UPDATE**

When testing, it runs successfully 6 times, inserting 300 rows.  On the 7th try, it always gives the same error shown above.  Furthermore, when I `INSERT` `(dc5e3082-e2eb-4bdf-a640-94e0f59411ed, 22)` by itself, it works fine.  My test is then able to continue and insert the remaining rows with no errors.

Comment: The merge statement is known to have bugs. Maybe you hit one. Please post the execution plan.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to add a `HOLDLOCK` on your `MERGE` statement. Try the following:

```
MERGE INTO Assets WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS Target
...
```

This avoids the race condition that you are running into. See more info [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx)

**EDIT**

Based on your update, the only other thing I can think of is that your temp table might have a duplicate record in it. Can you double check?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  You probably saved me (and others) some headache in the future, but unfortunately this didn't fix my problem.  Please see the updated question.

Comment: You are 100% correct.  I had a duplicate in my temp table.  Guess the HOLDLOCK advice is just a bonus!

Comment: On the other hand, I have seen adding HOLDLOCK to cause deadlocks, so there is no free lunch.